# css3 properties in Maple Browser

Tags: jquery, css, samsung-smart-tv

I am creating an application for the Samsung Smart TV which is using the Samsung's Maple Browser.

I need the background-size and webkit-background-size properties in my css files but they are not supported in the browser, and I don want to use the image tag.

their are js scripts for older versions of IE like css3pi etc, and by including them you can use the css3 properties n your application. Is their any script for Maple browser too?? or any  other way that I can use these properties in Maple Browser?

Answer (score 2):

CSS3PIE, specifically, uses behavior files, which are IE-specific, but most other scripts of the sort use feature detection and then add Javascript in that emulates the effect found in the CSS file. [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) is probably your best choice, assuming Maple supports Javascript. If it doesn't, then you're probably out of luck.